# How to align a View below a TextView in a RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to place a `View` below a `TextView` in a RelativeLayout.
The code below doesn't work.

Please help.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Following"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circulartextview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Followings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/flg1"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_Following"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/grey2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: For what purpose is this line exists __android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/tv_Following"__

Answer (score 2):

You only need `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your TextView
So to read

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Following"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circulartextview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Followings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
```

---

AND Remove the extra **+** from the @id references
So to read

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/flg1"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_Following"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/grey2" />
```

Otherwise, you are creating new ids with the name `tv_Following`.
And it can't reference the correct one.

Also note I changed this

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/tv_Following"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: Edited my answer. There was another issue witht the TextView: You only need `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: You are checking in relative layout only ?

Comment: Yes, RelativeLayout, as asked in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code by

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/flg1"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_Following"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/grey2" />
```

and define a size for your relative layout parent or for your flg1 view. For example

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="82dp">
```

Comment: You also have to define your relative layout height with a size bigger than 60dp. See my updated answer

Comment: Thats very bad idea to define specific height of layout it won't fit in all screens,i am trying to remove already mentioned dimensions in dp

Comment: then define the height of your flg1 view. With wrap_content and no content, you'll never get a visible result...